# Erasing numbers from the front of the row

Tags: probability, expectation

Numbers $1,2,\ldots,k$ are written in this order in a row. For $i=1,\ldots,k$, in the $i$th step, a random variable $V_i$ is drawn uniformly from the interval $[0,2i]$. If $V_i$ is greater than the first remaining number, that number is erased. What is the expected number of numbers that will be erased?

For example, if $k=1$, then we have the number $1$ and $V_1$ drawn from $[0,2]$, so $1/2$ numbers will be erased in expectation.

If $k=2$, then with probability $1/2$ we have $V_1>1$ and it is 50-50 whether the second number is erased. Otherwise $V_1<1$ and with probability $3/4$ the first number is erased. So the answer is $(1/2)(3/2)+(1/2)(3/4)=9/8$.

For $k=3$, a similar case analysis shows that the answer is $85/48$ (if I calculated correctly.) It could be that no closed form can be found in general. If so, upper/lower bounds would still be interesting.

Comment: I can't follow what you are trying to say, what do you mean by "first remaining number"?

Comment: If $k=2$, why isn't $V_1>1$ with probability $3/4$? Or am I misunderstanding the procedure?

Comment: @user160738 The first number that hasn't been erased

Comment: @rogerl $V_1$ is drawn from $[0,2]$, so $V_1>1$ with probability $1/2$

Comment: Ah, I misread $[0,2i]$ as $[0,2k]$.

Comment: For what it's worth, a Monte Carlo simulation of 100,000 tries for each value of $k$ from 2 to 20 gives a totally linear-looking graph that fits $-0.227543 + 0.663038x$ with an $R^2$ of over $99.99$.

Comment: That's very interesting - can we prove that it's indeed linear?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer That should be $0 \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{4}+1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{‌​2} \frac{1}{2} \right)+2\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{8}$ We are counting what was removed, not what remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E_{b,k}(a)$ be the expected number of erased numbers when you have already erased $a$ numbers and you are at the $b$th shot, out of $k$ shots.

Those can be defined for $1 \le a,b \le k+1$ by induction :
When you don't have any shot left, $E_{k+1,k}(a) = a$.
When you do you have $E_{b,k}(a) = \frac 1 {2b}((a+1) E_{b+1,k}(a) + (2b-a-1) E_{b+1,k}(a+1))$.

It turns out that every $E_{b,k}$ is an affine function :
Suppose $E_{b+1,k}(a) = pa + q$ for some $p,q \in \Bbb R$.
Then $E_{b,k}(a) = \frac 1{2b} ((a+1)(pa + q)+(2b-a-1)(p(a+1)+q))
= (1-\frac 1 {2b})pa + (q+(1-\frac 1 {2b})p)$.

So, focusing on those coefficients, we have $p_{b,k} = (1-\frac 1 {2b}) p_{b+1,k}$ and $q_{b,k} = q_{b+1,k} + p_{b,k}$

Since $p_{k,k}=1$ and $q_{k,k}=0$ we have :
$p_{b,k} = \prod_{j=b}^k (1-\frac 1 {2j})$ and
$q_{b,k} = \sum_{j=b}^k p_{j,k}$.

From there it's easy to find that when we fix $b$, the sequences $(q_{b,l})_{k \ge b-1}$ satisfy the recurrence relation $q_{b,k+1} = (1-\frac 1 {2k+2})(1 + q_{b,k})$.

Since we are interested in $E_{1,k}(0)=q_{1,k}$, we get the sequence (I'll rename it $(a_k)$) that starts with
$a_0 = 0$
$a_1 = \frac 12$
$a_2 = (\frac 12 + 1)\frac 34 = \frac 98$
$a_3 = (\frac 98 + 1)\frac 56 = \frac {85}{48}$ and so on.

---

Let $f_k(x) = (x+1)(1-\frac 1{2k+2})$.

We can check that $f_k(\frac {2k-1}3) = \frac {2(k+1)-1}3$ and $f_k(\frac 23 k) < \frac 23 (k+1)$.

Since the $f_k$ are increasing, this implies by induction that forall $k$, $\frac {2k-1}3 < a_k \le \frac 23k$.

Letting $b_k$ be the error term $a_k - \frac {2k-1}3$, we have $b_{k+1} = (1-\frac 1 {2k+2})b_k = \frac {2k+1}{2k+2}b_k$. Then for $k \ge 1$, $b_k = \frac {(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}b_0 = \frac{(2k-1)!}{2^{2k-1}(k-1)!k!}b_0 = 2^{1-2k}\binom{k-1}{2k-1}b_0$

Since $b_0 = \frac 13$, we get the closed form $a_k = \frac13 ((2k-1)+2^{1-2k}\binom{k}{2k-1})$

---

As for the asymptotics of $(a_k)$, one can use Stirling's formula to see that it has a development in $1/\sqrt k$ at any order.

$a_k = \frac 13 (2k -1 + \frac 1 {\sqrt{k \pi}} - \frac 1 {8\sqrt{k\pi}k} + \frac 1 {128\sqrt{k\pi}k^2} + \ldots + o(k^{n- \frac 12}))$.

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* Here are some other aspects towards a closed expression of the expectation values $E_k(X)$ of erased numbers. We focus at the probability tree for $k\geq 1$. This tree is some kind of *weighted* *[Leibniz harmonic triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_harmonic_triangle)*.

We derive a recurrence formula, detect some nice symmetric relations and give a representation of specific coefficients in terms of harmonic numbers. To find some relations, we start with a closer look of the cases $k=3,4$.

> **Example $k=3$**
>
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
> \{1,2,3\}&\frac{1}{2}&\{2,3\}&\frac{2}{4}&\{3\}&\color{blue}{\frac{3}{6}}&\emptyset\\
> \\
> \frac{1}{2}&&\frac{2}{4}&&\color{blue}{\frac{3}{6}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3\}&\frac{3}{4}&\{2,3\}&\color{blue}{\frac{4}{6}}&\{3\}\\
> \\
> \frac{1}{4}&&\color{blue}{\frac{2}{6}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3\}&\color{blue}{\frac{5}{6}}&\{2,3\}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3\}\\
> \end{array}

The probability tree  for $k=3$ represents the remaining sets of $\{1,2,3\}$ as nodes and the transition probabilities after each step $l=0,1,2,3$. We could consider this tree as a *triangle* rotated counter-clockwise by ${90}^\circ$. The sets which are possible in step $l$ are written down *diagonally*.

If we look at the top left entry $\{1,2,3\}$ we see we obtain with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ the *successor states* $\{2,3\}$ horizontally and $\{1,2,3\}$ vertically.

The    rightmost diagonal of transition probabilities shows the (blue) values
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{6}}\quad\color{blue}{\frac{5}{6}}\qquad\color{blue}{\frac{2}{6}}\quad\color{blue}{\frac{4}{6}}\qquad\color{blue}{\frac{3}{6}}\quad\color{blue}{\frac{3}{6}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
from bottom left to top right. We see the  resulting sets in the rightmost diagonal. E.g. the set $\{2,3\}$ in the rightmost diagonal is obtained from $\{1,2,3\}$ with probability $\frac{5}{6}$ and from $\{2,3\}$ with probability $\frac{2}{6}$.

We calculate the probabilities of the finally obtained sets:
\begin{array}{rl}
\emptyset&xxx\\
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}=\frac{6}{48}=\frac{1}{8}\\
\\
\{3\}&yxx+xyx+xxy\\
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{4}{6}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{4}{6}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}
=\frac{26}{48}=\frac{13}{24}\\
\\
\{2,3\}&yyx+yxy+xyy\\
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{6}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{6}
+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{2}{6}
=\frac{15}{48}=\frac{5}{16}\tag{1}\\
\\
\{1,2,3\}&yyy\\
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{48}\\
\end{array}

> We obtain for $k=3$   the  expected value $E_3(X)$ of   erased  numbers 
>   \begin{align*}
> E_3(x)&=3-\frac{13}{24}-2\frac{5}{16}-3\frac{1}{48}=\frac{85}{48}=1.7708\overline{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe nice regularities in (2)
>
> - The odd entries from left to right are $\frac{j}{2k}$ with $1\leq j \leq k$
> - The even entries from right to left are $\frac{k+j}{2k}$ with $0\leq j < k$
> - Two successive entries $\frac{2j+1}{2k},\frac{2j+2}{2k}$ sum up to $1$
>
> We also see, that the resulting probabilities starting from the beginning set $\{1,2,3\}$ are derived similarly as we do when adding up values in a pascal triangle or leibniz harmonic triangle but weighted with the corresponding transition probabilities. If we look at the resulting set $\{2,3\}$ after three steps, we see in (1) it can be reached with  probability $\frac{5}{16}$ and the *paths* are 
>   \begin{align*}
> yyx+yxy+xyy
> \end{align*}
>   meaning that we use all *paths* containing one $x$-step horizontally and two $y$-steps vertically when starting from $\{1,2,3\}$ in the probability tree when we want to reach $\{2,3\}$. The number of $y$ in the path description is bijectively related to the number of remaining elements in the set $\{2,3\}$.

These symmetries and also the same transition probabilities are valid for $k$ in general as we can see, when we look at the example for $k=4$.

> **Example $k=4$**
>
> \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
> \{1,2,3,4\}&\frac{1}{2}&\{2,3,4\}&\frac{2}{4}&\{3,4\}&\frac{3}{6}&\{4\}&\color{blue}{\frac{4}{6}}&\emptyset\\
> \\
> \frac{1}{2}&&\frac{2}{4}&&\frac{3}{6}&&\color{blue}{\frac{5}{8}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3,4\}&\frac{3}{4}&\{2,3,4\}&\frac{4}{6}&\{3,4\}&\color{blue}{\frac{5}{8}}&\{4\}\\
> \\
> \frac{1}{4}&&\frac{2}{6}&&\color{blue}{\frac{3}{8}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3,4\}&\frac{5}{6}&\{2,3,4\}&\color{blue}{\frac{6}{8}}&\{3,4\}\\
> \\
> \frac{1}{6}&&\color{blue}{\frac{2}{8}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3,4\}&\color{blue}{\frac{7}{8}}&\{2,3,4\}\\
> \\
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{8}}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3,4\}
> \end{array}

Obseve that we have in the leftmost three diagonals the same probability transitions as in the example for $k=3$.

> \begin{array}{rl}
> \emptyset&xxxx\\
> &\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}\frac{4}{8}=\frac{24}{384}=\frac{1}{16}\\
> \\
> \{4\}&yxxx+xyxx+xxyx+xxxy\\
> &\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{4}{6}\frac{5}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{4}{6}\frac{5}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}\frac{5}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}\frac{4}{8}
> =\frac{154}{384}=\frac{77}{192}\\
> \\
> \{3,4\}&yyxx+yxyx+yxxy+xyyx+xyxy+xxyy\\
> &\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{6}\frac{6}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{6}\frac{6}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{4}{6}\frac{3}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{2}{6}\frac{6}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{4}{6}\frac{3}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{3}{6}\frac{3}{8}
> =\frac{168}{384}=\frac{7}{16}\\
> \\
> \{2,3,4\}&yyyx+yyxy+yxyy+xyyy\\
> &\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{6}\frac{7}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{6}\frac{2}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{8}
> +\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{4}\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{8}
> =\frac{37}{384}\\
> \\
> \{1,2,3,4\}&yyyy\\
> &\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{384}\\
> \end{array}
>
> We obtain for $k=4$  the   expected value $E_4(X)$ of   erased  numbers 
>   \begin{align*}
> E_4(x)&=4-\frac{77}{192}-2\frac{7}{16}-3\frac{37}{384}-4\frac{1}{384}=\frac{931}{384}=2.4244791\overline{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> From these examples it is easy to derive a recurrence relation for the transition probabilities.

$$ $$

> **Recurrence relation:**
>
> The example trees above together with the observations at the end of example  $k=3$ indicate the following recurrence relation of the transition probabilities.
>
> Let $p_{k,l}$ denote the probability to obtain the set $\{l+1,l+2,\ldots,k\}$ when starting with the set $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ with $0\leq l < k$. The following holds valid
>
> \begin{align*}
>  p_{k,l}&=\frac{2k-l}{2k}p_{k-1,l-1}+\frac{l+1}{2k}p_{k-1,l}&\qquad 1\leq l<k\tag{3}\\
>  p_{k,0}&=\frac{1}{2^kk!}&\qquad k\geq 1\\
>  p_{k,k}&=\frac{1}{2^k}&\qquad k\geq 1
>  \end{align*}
>
> The expectation value $E_k(X)$ describing the number of expected erased numbers  is given by
>   \begin{align*}
> E_k(x)=k-\sum_{l=1}^kkp_{k,l}\qquad k\geq 0
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Generating functions and harmonic numbers:**
>
> It would be nice to derive a generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x,y)=\sum_{k,l\geq 0}p_{k,l}x^ky^l
> \end{align*}
>   for the probabilities $p_{k,l}$ and to obtain a *closed expression* with the help of $A(x,y)$. This approach leads to a first order linear partial differential equation in $x$ and $y$ which I wasn't able solve. Somewhat more modest we focus on generating functions corresponding to a *row* or a *column* of the matrix representation in the examples above.
>
> We observe that according to (3) the generating functions for $p_{k,0}$ and $p_{k,k}$ are
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k\geq 0}p_{k,0}x^k&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^kk!}x^k=\exp\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
> \sum_{k\geq 0}p_{k,k}x^k&=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}
> \end{align*}
>   So, we derive a *geometric series* for the entries of the first row in the matrix representation of the probability tree and an exponential series for the entries of the first column.
>
> We consider now the generating functions for column entries. We define for $m\geq 0$ the generating function $T_m(x)$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> T_m(x)=\sum_{k\geq m}p_{k,k-m}x^k
> \end{align*}

This corresponds to the *row entries* of matrix representation of the probability tree. We obtain from (3) the following recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
 p_{k,k-m}&=\frac{k+m}{2k}p_{k-1,k-m-1}+\frac{k-m+1}{2k}p_{k-1,k-m}&\qquad 1\leq m<k\tag{4}\\
 p_{k,0}&=\frac{1}{2^kk!}&\qquad k\geq 1\\
 p_{k,k}&=\frac{1}{2^k}&\qquad k\geq 1
\end{align*}

> We consider the special case $m=1$ and show the following is valid for the probabilities $p_{k,k-1}$ with $k\geq 1$
>
> - The probabilities $p_{k,k-1}$ follow the recurrence relation
>
> \begin{align*}
>  p_{k,k-1}&=\frac{k+1}{2k}p_{k-1,k-2}+\frac{k}{2k}p_{k-1,k-1}&\qquad 1\leq m<k\tag{5}\\
>  p_{k,0}&=\frac{1}{2^kk!}&\qquad k\geq 1\\
>  p_{k,k}&=\frac{1}{2^k}&\qquad k\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>
> - A generating function $T_1(x)$ for the probabilities $p_{k,k-1}$ is
>     \begin{align*}
>   T_1(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1}p_{k,k-1}x^k=-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}\tag{6}
>   \end{align*}
> - The generating function $T_1(x)$ fulfills the following linear differential equation
>     \begin{align*}
>   \left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)T_1^{\prime}(x)=T_1(x)+\frac{1}{2\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}\tag{7}
>   \end{align*}
> - The probabilities $p_{k,k-1}$ are the generalised harmonic numbers $H_k^{(2)}$
>
> \begin{align*}
> p_{k,k-1}=H_k^{(2)}=\sum_{l=1}^{k}H_l\qquad\qquad k\geq 1\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

The recurrence relation (5) follows immediately from (4) by setting $m=1$. In order to obtain the generating function $T_1(x)$ we use the recurrence relation (5) and obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\geq 2}2kp_{k,k-1}x^k&=\sum_{k\geq 2}(k+1)p_{k-1,k-2}x^k+\sum_{k\geq 2}2kp_{k-1,k-1}x^k\\
2xD_x\sum_{k\geq 2}p_{k,k-1}x^k&=\left(xD_x+I\right)\sum_{k\geq 2}p_{k-1,k-2}x^k+xD_x\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}x^k\tag{9}\\
2xD_x\left(T_1(x)-\frac{x}{2}\right)&=\left(xD_x+I\right)\sum_{k\geq 1}p_{k,k-1}x^{k+1}
+2xD_x\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}-1-\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
2xD_xT_1(x)-x&=\left(xD_x+I\right)(xT_1(x))+\frac{4x}{(x-2)^2}-x\tag{10}\\
2xD_xT_1(x)&=\left(x^2D_x+2xI\right)T_1(x)+\frac{4x}{(x-2)^2}\tag{11}\\
(2x-x^2)D_xT_1(x)&=2xT_1(x)+\frac{4x}{(x-2)^2}\\
\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)D_xT_1(x)&=T_1(x)+\frac{1}{2\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}
\end{align*}

and (7) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (9) we use the operator notation $D_x=\frac{d}{dx}$ for the derivation and the identity operator $I$.
- In (10) we do some index shifting und use the formula for the geometric series
- In (11) we use the Leibniz product rule $D_xx=xD_x+I$

Verifying that $T_1(x)=-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$ fulfills the differential equation and noting that $T_1(0)=0$ the claim (6) follows.

Since a generating function for the *[harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)* $H_k=\sum_{l=1}^k\frac{1}{l}$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}H_kx^k=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}
\end{align*}
and multiplication of a generating function with $\frac{1}{1-x}$ means *summing up the coefficients*, the claim (8) follows.

$$ $$

> **Possible ways to proceed:**
>
> It would be nice to find an explicit expression for the $p_{k,l}$ with $0\leq l < k$, which seem to be strongly connected with harmonic numbers. Some ideas to proceed are
>
> - Derive a generating functions $T_m(x)$ for $m\geq 2$ which could help to indicate the structure of the generating function $A(x,y)$
> - Find a generating function $A(x,y)$ by directly using the recurrence relation (3)
> - The kind of obtaining the probabilities $p_{k,l}$ as *weighted paths* via $x$-steps and $y$-steps as mentioned above indicates also a relationship to *[$q$-binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)*.

Answer (score 1):

Brute-force calculation for $k=1$ to $25$ shows that the curve very quickly becomes near-linear.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
k & EV(k) & EV(k)-EV(k-1) \\
\hline
1 & 0.500 & 0.500000 \\
2 & 1.125 & 0.625000 \\
3 & 1.771 & 0.645833 \\
4 & 2.424 & 0.653646 \\
5 & 3.082 & 0.657552 \\
6 & 3.742 & 0.659831 \\
7 & 4.403 & 0.661296 \\
8 & 5.065 & 0.662303 \\
9 & 5.728 & 0.663030 \\
10 & 6.392 & 0.663575 \\
11 & 7.056 & 0.663997 \\
12 & 7.720 & 0.664331 \\
13 & 8.385 & 0.664600 \\
14 & 9.050 & 0.664822 \\
15 & 9.715 & 0.665006 \\
16 & 10.380 & 0.665162 \\
17 & 11.045 & 0.665295 \\
18 & 11.711 & 0.665409 \\
19 & 12.376 & 0.665508 \\
20 & 13.042 & 0.665595 \\
21 & 13.707 & 0.665672 \\
22 & 14.373 & 0.665740 \\
23 & 15.039 & 0.665800 \\
24 & 15.705 & 0.665854 \\
25 & 16.371 & 0.665903 \\
\hline\end{array}$$